# Installing rocket chip generator

Tags: riscv, rocket-chip

I've been trying to install rocket-chip generator.

This is what I have done

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip.git
$ cd rocket-chip
$ export ROCKETCHIP='pwd'
$ git submodule update --init
$ export RISCV=/home/user1/rocket-chip
```

and github's README says i should install riscv-tools

so, I've created /home/fulladder/riscv-tools

and trying to install spike, the isa simulator

I typed

```
$ apt-get install device-tree-compiler
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
```

But I can't understand next instruction means

```
$ ../configure --prefix=$RISCV --with-fesvr=$RISCV
```

Could you tell me what i have to do next

And, I'm trying to learn Rocket chip generator and RISC-V

Could you recommend some books or website to learn these two part

Comment: It literally means to type that into a command line…

Comment: but.. terminal says "bash: ../configure: No such file or directory"